# How to compare a column with same number and take the bigger one from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset:

[image: df]

I want to take the FIPS column and compare the same FIPS number to the `candidatevotes` and delete the row that has the smaller `candidatevotes` number.

I could do it manually but want to see if there is some python way to do this.

Comment: Hey TCL, do you have any code you have tried?  It is very doable with python, but Stack Overflow is not a coding service it is for getting past issues/errors.  So do some research an let us know what you have tried and where it is not working in python and I am sure you will get some help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I have no idea (maybe a for loop) and don't want to spend time on it as its not required for my project so I'll just do it manually.